# Does Google Fit include a HL7 CDA viewer like iOS HealthKit does?

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk, hl7-cda

iOS HealthKit is able to display locally the HL7 CDA documents a patient download from a Patient Portal.

Does Google Fit include a HL7 CDA viewer like iOS HealthKit does?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with iOS HealthKit. Can you provide more details as to what the *viewer* actually does? Are the HL7 CDA documents a specific file (what file type) that is stored locally and then opened using the HealthKit? Or is it just like a PDF file?

Comment: HL7 CDA is the standard way of representing clinical documents ([link]http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=7). On iOS HealthKit if you get an HL7 CDA, for example downloaded form a patient portal, you are able to save it locally to health kit, and view it with its HL7 build in CDA viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

There is currently no option/function to view HL7 CDA files with the use of Google Fit.

---

Stuff (that I learned) that may help other who read this in the future:

The way I understood things after skimming through the [HL7 link](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=7) you provided in the comments and with the some other sources ([Apple HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit), [9to5mac post](https://9to5mac.com/2016/06/15/hands-on-hl7-ccd-health-records-ios-10-health-kit/)), the data included in the HL7 CDA files are clinically in-depth. From the HL7 link:

> A CDA can contain any type of clinical content -- typical CDA documents would be a Discharge Summary, Imaging Report, Admission & Physical, Pathology Report and more.

This caters to almost (if not) all health related documents, wherein [Google Fit](https://developers.google.com/fit/) focuses more on (if not solely to) **Fitness**.

With all that said, basing from the *9to5mac* post, it seems that the HL7 CDA files are actually XML files. So I guess what you could do is implement an XML parser and display the files the in a more neat and organized way (similar to how HealthKit does it, I guess).

<sub>I also did a quick search to see if maybe I can give you some references, but it looks like no one has done a HL7 CDA viewer app/library for Android yet.</sub>